# How do I pass two different edit-text by a button, to a new activity with a text-view as a result?

Tags: android-intent, android-studio, android-edittext, textview, android-button, android

I'm fairly new at programming with Android Studio, and basically what I'm trying to do is, when someone type their First Name in an Edit Text and their Last Name in another Edit Text on MainActivity, they click a button and it shows the Full Name as a TextView in the SecondActivity.

As I know by know, by searches I've made, I need to use Intent to pass down information between activities, and for the button to work I need to use "onClick" on the layout xml, and then setOnClickListener on MainActivity ? I just don't now exactly where.

But the main thing I want to know here, is how do I get **TWO** Edit Text, by Intent, to show up on the new activity, by the click of the button.

I've tried an example I found online, but it crashes on my bq Aquaris E4,5 (API 19), not sure why.

Also tried doing it by myself, using the help of that previous example and this video [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45gq0Q8GFMM)

But it got rather confusing, since the video ain't what I want exactly, but the other example was exactly what I wanted, but didn't work, it's this one [Tuturial passing data between activities](http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/241-lesson-28-extras-passing-data-using-intent.html)

If anyone can help me out to get what I described in the beginning to work, I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance,
Best Regards,
Sir Rudi

EDIT: This is what I wrote on my Android Manifest, on the example I tried:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"  >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ace_of_spades_inc.mynameapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: which step are you stuck at?

Comment: What do you mean which step? From the example?

Comment: Yes, from the example. Which step you don't get similar results?

Comment: From the lesson example, I did everything, no errors on the coding inside Android Studio, but when I run the app on my external device, as soon as I click the button it crashes. Even if I don't write anything on the EditText fields. 

At the end of the example also says  "Don’t forget to register Activity inside manifest", I'm going to edit my main post with what I wrote on my Manifest.